# (JGraphT) Export Graph<String, DefaultEdge> as DOT

Tags: graph, dot, jgrapht

I use the [jgrapht](https://jgrapht.org/) library and I have directed Graphs with **Strings** as **vertices** and **DefaultEdges** as **edges**. 
Now I wonder how to export my graph in the DOT format. 
What would be the best approach for the export?
From the jgraph documentation i understand, that I can use the DOTExporter class
https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/nio/dot/DOTExporter.html
For instantiating that class I need a Writer and a VertexProvider which I struggle to instantiate from my given graph.

This is the type of graph I want to export:

```
Graph<String, DefaultEdge> graph
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two examples of exporting a graph in DOT format using the `DOTExporter`. In the first example, no `vertexIDProvider` is provided. As a result, the exporter does not know how to name your vertices, so it simply assigns each vertex a unique number. In the second example, I provide a `vertexIDProvider`. The `vertexIDProvider` is a `Function<V,​String> vertexIdProvider` which maps a vertex to a String. In 2nd example I simply map a vertex to its String representation.
Finally, In the examples I use a simple `Writer`. In your implementation you might want to use a `FileWriter` to write the result to an actual file.

```
//Create a graph with some vertices and edges
Graph<String, DefaultEdge> graph=new SimpleGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
Graphs.addAllVertices(graph, Arrays.asList("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"));
graph.addEdge("v1", "v2");
graph.addEdge("v2", "v3");
graph.addEdge("v3", "v4");
graph.addEdge("v4", "v1");

//Create the exporter (without ID provider)
DOTExporter<String, DefaultEdge> exporter=new DOTExporter<>();
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
exporter.exportGraph(graph, writer);
System.out.println(writer.toString());

//Create the exporter (with ID provider)
DOTExporter<String, DefaultEdge> exporter2=new DOTExporter<>(v -> v.toString());
writer = new StringWriter();
exporter2.exportGraph(graph, writer);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Output:

```
strict graph G {
  1;
  2;
  3;
  4;
  1 -- 2;
  2 -- 3;
  3 -- 4;
  4 -- 1;
}

strict graph G {
  v1;
  v2;
  v3;
  v4;
  v1 -- v2;
  v2 -- v3;
  v3 -- v4;
  v4 -- v1;
}
```

A more elaborate example can be found in the [user documentation](https://jgrapht.org/guide/UserOverview#graph-serialization-and-exportimport).More examples can be found in the [DOTExporterTest](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-io/src/test/java/org/jgrapht/nio/dot/DOTExporterTest.java) class.

Comment: Thanks Joris for your help. I have figured it out myself by now. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I export my graph as .dot now:

```
DOTExporter<String, DefaultEdge> exporter = new DOTExporter<>();
        exporter.setVertexAttributeProvider((v) -> {
            Map<String, Attribute> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            map.put("label", DefaultAttribute.createAttribute(v));
            return map;
});
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
exporter.exportGraph(Graph, writer);
```